# Can't access subpages in WordPress due to change of url (WP and site)

Tags: wordpress, url

I have access to my WordPress site and the homepage, but I still can't access the subpages, it says 'Sorry! You're not Authorized to access this website!'.

I've already done the following steps:

1. Pasted the following in the theme's functions.php

   `update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://yourpageserver.com/acolade-demo/' );
   update_option( 'home', 'https://yourpageserver.com/acolade-demo/' );
   global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();`
2. After doing this, I've got my access back for my WordPress, so I removed the codes from my functions.php. I wasn't aware that I have no access for the subpages at this moment.
3. After seeing that I've got no access on the subpages, I tried to paste those codes back, but still no success..

I have been searching the net for help for hours. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Open your wp-config.php and paste the bellow code at the top,

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourpageserver.com/acolade-demo/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourpageserver.com/acolade-demo/');
```

and save.

Then go to WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalink -> Save it.

Comment: Thank you sir. I forgot to mention that I already did this. But after doing so, you won't be able to edit those urls in WP Admin > Settings > Permalink. And also, still no access on the subpages.

Comment: Who told you after changing url you won't able to log into WP-Admin?

Comment: After changing the urls (wp and site links) in WP-ADMIN > Settings > General , you'll be automatically logged out, and it says 'Sorry! You're not Authorized to access this website!'.

Comment: use the new url to login again.

Answer (score 0):

Open Database and table wp_options

Then find "WP_HOME" and "WP_SITEURL" and replace it with
your base folder url ie https://yourpageserver.com/acolade-demo/

Then check your site in browser

Comment: Thank you sir. But on my word press directory there is no wp_options. Are you referring to wp_config? The most relative file is wp_settings but there's no url to configure in there. Can you please tell me where to find it?

Comment: "wp_options" is the table name in your database

Answer (score 0):

My problem is fixed. I renamed my folder containing the wordpress files, then I also changed the urls in WP-ADMIN > SETTINGS > GENERAL. At this point I got my access removed again, so I pasted these codes back:

`update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://yourpageserver.com/accolade-demo/' );
 update_option( 'home', 'https://yourpageserver.com/accolade-demo/' );`

Notice that the link is now 'accolade-demo' because this should be the correct link and name. Now I've got my access back including the subpages.