# Changed mac username, now WordPress permalinks not working

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I changed the user folder name on my macbook, now I get a 404 when accessing a child page via localhost using my local apache2 server.

I can't 100% guarantee this is what is causing my woes, but that is a major recent change - and since then I can't load interior pages/posts.

`eg: http://example.dev/childpage`

Homepage loads, WordPress Admin works - just subpages.

Trouble-shooting so far:

1. Saved Permalinks in the WordPress Admin to regenerate them
2. Updated /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhost.conf
3. Grepped /etc/apache2/ to verified no old username
4. Restarted Apache (restarted my computer!)
5. Grepped /Users/newuser recursively for old username
6. Followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804546/cant-access-subpages-in-wordpress-due-to-change-of-url-wp-and-site#_=_) using *functions.php* and *wp-config.php* methods and regeneration steps
7. Verified via *phpinfo();* and */etc/apache2/httpd.conf* that mod_rewrite is enabled
8. .htaccess contains typical single site entry

Would be happy to hear from someone who's found the secret key.
Thanks!

Comment: For reasons I don't understand, Wordpress saves full paths in lots of places in the database. Anytime I've done something like this, I've ended up exporting the database, doing a find/replace on the export, then replacing the old database with the modified data.

Comment: Check the `.htaccess` file and see if you don't have any hardcoded paths here. Alternatively, go to the permalinks section of the admin and confirm again. it will regenerate the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done all the above steps, and still seeing no success with the typical .htaccess in the docs, I found that adding /index.php/ to the custom slug revives things. This concludes that all hope is not lost and that I just need to take a deeper look at the .htaccess rewrite rules to omit the unsightly index.php.

EDIT:
Answer via:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/403-forbidden-error-wordpress-htaccess/

Add “Options +FollowSymLinks”  to your .htaccess file  at start of the file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks everyone!